# Groupby time bins in multilevel index

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a sparsely filled data frame that looks like this:

```
entity_id                                                              59e75f2b9e182f68cf25721d  59e75f2bc0bd722a5f395ee9  59e75f2c05e40310ebe1f433  ... 
organisation_id          group_id                 datetime                                                                                           ... 
59e7515edb84e482acce8339 59e75177575fc94638c1f8e7 2018-04-01 02:01:00                       NaN                       NaN                       NaN  ... 
                                                  2018-04-01 02:02:00                       NaN                      2.15                       NaN  ... 
                                                  2018-04-01 02:03:00                       NaN                       NaN                     3.689  ... 
                                                  2018-04-01 02:04:00                       NaN                       NaN                       NaN  ... 
                                                  2018-04-01 02:05:00                       NaN                       NaN                       NaN  ... 
...                                                                                         ...                       ...                       ...  ... 
                         5cb590649f18c69541d34f7a 2019-04-01 01:55:00                       NaN                       NaN                       NaN  ... 
                                                  2019-04-01 01:56:00                       NaN                       NaN                       NaN  ... 
                                                  2019-04-01 01:57:00                       NaN                       NaN                       NaN  ... 
                                                  2019-04-01 01:58:00                       NaN                       NaN                       NaN  ... 
                                                  2019-04-01 01:59:00                       NaN                       NaN                       NaN  ...
```

I would like to group this frame by `group_id` and 10-minute bins applied to the datetime index (for each group i want values that occurred inside the same 10 minute window to be grouped so i can take the mean over columns, disregarding the minute portion of the datetime index essentially).

I have tried using `pd.Grouper(freq='10T')` but that doesn't work in conjunction with multilevel indices it would seem.

```
group_mean = frame.groupby(
    pd.Grouper(freq='10T'), level='datetime').mean(axis=1)
```

This gives me the error message

```
TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'MultiIndex'
```

For reference, my wanted output should look something like this:

```
                                                                      group_mean
organisation_id          group_id                 datetime                                                                                            
59e7515edb84e482acce8339 59e75177575fc94638c1f8e7 2018-04-01 02:10:00 mean(axis=1)                  
                                                  2018-04-01 02:20:00 mean(axis=1)                      
                                                  ...                       

                         5cb590649f18c69541d34f7a 2019-04-01 01:50:00 mean(axis=1)                      
                                                  2019-04-01 02:00:00 mean(axis=1)                      
                                                  ...
```

where `mean(axis=1)` is the mean of all columns that are not `NaN` for that specific group and time bin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution need `DatetimeIndex`, so first convert another levels to columns and add it to `groupby` in `list`:

*Notice*: Mean is per groups, not per columns.

```
group_mean = (frame.reset_index(['organisation_id','group_id'])
                   .groupby(['organisation_id',
                             'group_id',
                              pd.Grouper(freq='10T',level='datetime')])
                   .mean())
```

If need mean per columns:

```
df = frame.mean(axis=1)
```

Comment: I should have added that per column, only one value can be not `NaN` per 10 minute bin. I will accept it once i've tried it but i think this will work, thanks!

Comment: @sobek - Maybe the best test it in some small data, and then apply to large one.

Comment: I had to use `group_mean = frame.reset_index(
        ['organisation_id', 'group_id']).groupby(
            ['organisation_id', 'group_id', pd.Grouper(
                freq='10T', level='datetime')]).mean().mean(axis=1)` but now it works, thank you!